# Get a list of all subsequences

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I'm looking for an equivalent to the [`subsequences`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:subsequences) function in Scala. I cannot find it in [scala.collection.Seq](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.Seq), maybe it is defined somewhere else. But where?

I think the problem is well known. As an example, given the sequence `"abc"`, the list of all subsequences is  `["","a","b","ab","c","ac","bc","abc"]`.

A quick and dirty implementation in Scala would be as follows:

```
(for {ys <- xs.inits.toList; zs <- ys.tails} yield zs).distinct
```

But it'd be nice to use something already defined, and more efficient.

Comment: far from an answer, but this particular example has another solution: `"abc".toSet.subsets().map(_.mkString("")).toList`.

Comment: It is not really related to Haskell, you should remove the Haskell tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `combinations`:

```
(0 to xs.length).toIterator.flatMap(i => xs.combinations(i))
```

Comment: Please note that this does not return subsequences of contiguous elements. The code above will return `[a, b, c, ab, ac, bc]` which differs from the expected `["","a","b","ab","c","ac","bc","abc"]`.

Comment: Pushed the off-by-ones out by one, should be correct now.

Comment: The output for `"aba"` is missing the sequence `"ba"`.